# How to make a hollow box using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, box

So I have an assignment to print a box (hollow) according to the user-given output. The function names and purposes are assigned.

When I call this code with **print_box()** and enter the answers, I cant get a box.

Code:

```
def print_line(ch, size):
    print(ch)
    for index in range(4):
        print(ch, end ="")
    print(ch)

def get_size():
    n = int(input("Enter a number between 3 and 8: "))
    while n < 3:
        n = int(input("Wrong, enter a number between 3 and 8: "))
    return n

def get_char():
    ch = input("Enter a character (* or -): ")
    while ch not in ‘*-’:
        ch = input("Please try again: ")
    return ch

def print_box():
    size = get_size()
    ch = get_char()
    print_line(ch, size)

print_box()
```

Comment: Please start by formatting your code. Don't apologise for it - fix it :P

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Among other things, the user tour points you to notes on how to format your posting.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is that you've written a lot of supporting code well before you've figured out how to print *any* box.  Among other things, you can't print the two types of lines that you need.  Drop the overhead for now; test this with a simple main program of

```
print_line("*", 5)
```

When you have **print_line** working, then back up to

```
print_box("*", 5)
```

Once **that** is working, *then* you can fiddle with input and validation.

In the meantime, here's a simple change to help you test, so you can tell which characters come from which **print** statements:

```
def print_line(ch, size):
    print("1")
    for index in range(4):
        print("2", end ="")
    print("3")
```

Output:

```
1
22223
```

Does that show you some of the problems in your logic?

Keep going: you're doing a lot of things right.